# How to set the radiuses of each band on a sunburt chart?

Tags: dc.js

I'm using the new sunburst chart for a 2 level hierarchy [country,region] and it works great, but I have one issue:

the second band (region) is tiny compared to the first one (country). How to adjust the radius to it works better visually?

Comment: Hrrm, seems to be a design decision to use sqrt(y) based on [Mike's original block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423). The [original sunburst design](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/gvu/ii/sunburst/) apparently used constant radius rings. You could hack on `buildArcs()` and the `d3.partition` initialization in `partitionNodes()` in sunburst-chart.js and see if you come up with other options. In a quick try, I was able to change the result but didn't figure out how to get something good.